# Pandas DataFrame Groupby two columns and get counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.6, 2.5, 3.4,2.6,2.6,3.4,3.4,2.6,1.1,1.1,3.3], 
    list('AAABBBBABCBDDD'), 
    [1.1, 1.7, 2.5, 2.6, 3.3, 3.8,4.0,4.2,4.3,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.7,4.8], 
    ['x/y/z','x/y','x/y/z/n','x/u','x','x/u/v','x/y/z','x','x/u/v/b','-','x/y','x/y/z','x','x/u/v/w'],
    ['1','3','3','2','4','2','5','3','6','3','5','1','1','1']
]).T
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
```

df:

```
   col1 col2 col3     col4 col5
0   1.1    A  1.1    x/y/z    1
1   1.1    A  1.7      x/y    3
2   1.1    A  2.5  x/y/z/n    3
3   2.6    B  2.6      x/u    2
4   2.5    B  3.3        x    4
5   3.4    B  3.8    x/u/v    2
6   2.6    B    4    x/y/z    5
7   2.6    A  4.2        x    3
8   3.4    B  4.3  x/u/v/b    6
9   3.4    C  4.5        -    3
10  2.6    B  4.6      x/y    5
11  1.1    D  4.7    x/y/z    1
12  1.1    D  4.7        x    1
13  3.3    D  4.8  x/u/v/w    1
```

I want to get the count by each row like following. Expected Output:

```
col5 col2 count
1    A      1
     D      3
2    B      2
etc...
```

How to get my expected output? And I want to find largest count for each 'col2' value?

Comment: Note on performance, including alternatives: [Pandas groupby.size vs series.value_counts vs collections.Counter with multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328246/pandas-groupby-size-vs-series-value-counts-vs-collections-counter-with-multiple)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Followed by @Andy's answer, you can do following to solve your second question:

```
In [56]: df.groupby(['col5','col2']).size().reset_index().groupby('col2')[[0]].max()
Out[56]: 
      0
col2   
A     3
B     2
C     1
D     3
```

Answer (score 269):

You are looking for [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation):

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['col5', 'col2']).size()
Out[11]:
col5  col2
1     A       1
      D       3
2     B       2
3     A       3
      C       1
4     B       1
5     B       2
6     B       1
dtype: int64
```

---

To get the same answer as waitingkuo (the "second question"), but slightly cleaner, is to groupby the level:

```
In [12]: df.groupby(['col5', 'col2']).size().groupby(level=1).max()
Out[12]:
col2
A       3
B       2
C       1
D       3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: So what do you mean by "level=1"?

Answer (score 50):

### Idiomatic solution that uses only a single groupby

```
(df.groupby(['col5', 'col2']).size() 
   .sort_values(ascending=False) 
   .reset_index(name='count') 
   .drop_duplicates(subset='col2'))

  col5 col2  count
0    3    A      3
1    1    D      3
2    5    B      2
6    3    C      1
```

**Explanation**

The result of the groupby `size` method is a Series with `col5` and `col2` in the index. From here, you can use another groupby method to find the maximum value of each value in  `col2` but it is not necessary to do. You can simply sort all the values descendingly and then keep only the rows with the first occurrence of `col2` with the `drop_duplicates` method.

Comment: Note: `.drop_duplicates(subset='col2'))` is only to answer the second question: `And I want to find the largest count for each 'col2' value?` and, thus, will remove duplicates with smaller count values.

Answer (score 32):

Inserting **data** into a pandas dataframe and **providing column name**.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','C','A','B','C','A','B','B','A','A'], ['ONE','TWO','ONE','ONE','ONE','TWO','ONE','TWO','ONE','THREE']]).T
df.columns = [['Alphabet','Words']]
print(df)   #printing dataframe.
```

This is our printed data:

[image]

For making a ***group of dataframe in pandas and counter***, 
You need to provide one more column which counts the grouping, **let's call that column as, *"COUNTER"* in  dataframe**.

Like this:

```
df['COUNTER'] =1       #initially, set that counter to 1.
group_data = df.groupby(['Alphabet','Words'])['COUNTER'].sum() #sum function
print(group_data)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If you want to construct a DataFrame as a final result (not a pandas Series), use the `as_index=` parameter:

```py
df.groupby(['col5', 'col2'], as_index=False).size()
```

[image: res1]

---

To get the final desired output, `pivot_table` may be used as well (instead of double `groupby`):

```py
df.pivot_table(index='col5', columns='col2', aggfunc='size').max()
```

[image: res2]

---

If you don't want to count NaN values, you can use `groupby.count`:

```py
df.groupby(['col5', 'col2']).count()
```

[image: res3]

Note that since each column may have different number of non-NaN values, unless you specify the column, a simple `groupby.count` call may return different counts for each column as in the example above. For example, the number of non-NaN values in `col1` after grouping by `['col5', 'col2']` is as follows:

```py
df.groupby(['col5', 'col2'])['col1'].count()
```

[image: res4]

Answer (score 5):

Should you want to add a new column (say 'count_column') containing the groups' counts into the dataframe:

```
df.count_column=df.groupby(['col5','col2']).col5.transform('count')
```

(I picked 'col5' as it contains no nan)

Answer (score 3):

Since pandas 1.1.0., you can [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts) on a DataFrame:

```
out = df[['col5','col2']].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Output:

```
col5  col2
1     A       1
      D       3
2     B       2
3     A       3
      C       1
4     B       1
5     B       2
6     B       1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -3):

You can just use the built-in function count follow by the groupby function

```
df.groupby(['col5','col2']).count()
```