# python equivalent of R table

Tags: python, r, frequency

I have a list

```
[[12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0]]
```

I want to count the frequency of each element in this list. 
Something like

```
freq[[12,6]] = 40
```

In R this can be obtained with the `table` function. Is there anything similar in python3?

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A `Counter` object from the `collections` library will function like that.

```
from collections import Counter

x = [[12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0]]

# Since the elements passed to a `Counter` must be hashable, we have to change the lists to tuples.
x = [tuple(element) for element in x]

freq = Counter(x)

print freq[(12,6)]

# Result:  28
```

Answer (score 222):

Pandas has a built-in function called `value_counts()`.

Example: if your DataFrame has a column with values as 0's and 1's, and you want to count the total frequencies for each of them, then simply use this:

```
df.colName.value_counts()
```

Comment: This should really be the top answer.

Comment: `value_counts` is a method of the class ´pandas.Series´, not `pandas.DataFrame`. It only counts from columns, not dataframes, unlike the R table function.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to scroll down; I've previously upvoted this answer but I forgot!

Comment: Use `df.colName.value_counts(dropna=False)` to include `NaN` (missing value count).

Answer (score 46):

Supposing you need to convert the data to a [pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) anyway, so that you have

```
L = [[12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=('a', 'b'))
```

then you can do as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17679517/3275967), using [`groupby.size()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation):

```
tab = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).size()
```

`tab` looks as follows:

```
In [5]: tab
Out[5]:
a   b
0   6    19
6   0    20
12  0    33
    6    28
dtype: int64
```

and can easily be changed to a table form with [`unstack()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
In [6]: tab.unstack()
Out[6]:
b      0     6
a
0    NaN  19.0
6   20.0   NaN
12  33.0  28.0
```

[Fill `NaN`s](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and [convert to `int`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) at your own leisure!

Comment: THIS is functionally equivalent to the R `table` function.

Comment: *This* is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: i tried using dropna = False in groupby() to include the NaNs, but it doesn't work. How else could the NaNs be included in the table?

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira can you provide a failing example? Inserting a `float("nan")` in `L` and using `df.groupby(['a', 'b'], dropna=False).size()` works fine On My Machine(tm) :-)

Answer (score 31):

```
import pandas
x = [[12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0]] 
ps = pandas.Series([tuple(i) for i in x])
counts = ps.value_counts()
print counts
```

you will get the result like:

```
(12, 0)    33
(12, 6)    28
(6, 0)     20
(0, 6)     19
```

and for `[(12,6)]` you will get exact number, here `28`

more about `pandas`, which is powerful Python data analysis toolkit, you can read in official doc: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

UPDATE:

If order does not matter just use sorted:
`ps = pandas.Series([tuple(sorted(i)) for i in x])` after that result is:

```
(0, 6)     39
(0, 12)    33
(6, 12)    28
```

Comment: is there an easy way with pandas to consider equal permutation of elements? [12,0] = [0,12] ?

Comment: @Donbeo see update. Sorted should be easiest way to do it ;-)

Comment: set is ok if you accept removing of repetitions. as far as you don't care about difference between [0,1,1] and [0,1] using set is ok.

Comment: Use `df.colName.value_counts(dropna=False)` to include `NaN` (missing value count).

Answer (score 18):

IMHO, pandas offers a better solution for this "tabulation" problem:

One dimension:

```
my_tab = pd.crosstab(index = df["feature_you_r_interested_in"],
                              columns="count")
```

Proportion count:

```
my_tab/my_tab.sum()
```

Two-dimensions (with totals):

```
cross = pd.crosstab(index=df["feat1"], 
                             columns=df["feat2"],
                             margins=True)

cross
```

Also, as mentioned by other coleagues, pandas value_counts method could be all you need. It is so good that you can have the counts as percentages if you want:

```
df['your feature'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

I'm very grateful for this blog:

http://hamelg.blogspot.com.br/2015/11/python-for-data-analysis-part-19_17.html

Comment: The link doesn't work. This one does:
http://hamelg.blogspot.com/2015/11/python-for-data-analysis-part-19_17.html

Comment: Thanks for your first solution!
By the way, you can use the argument `normalize='columns'` in crosstab to get proportion count.

Answer (score 10):

In Numpy, the best way I've found of doing this is to use [`unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), e.g:

```py
import numpy as np

# OPs data
arr = np.array([[12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0]])

values, counts = np.unique(arr, axis=0, return_counts=True)

# into a dict for presentation
{tuple(a):b for a,b in zip(values, counts)}
```

giving me: `{(0, 6): 19, (6, 0): 20, (12, 0): 33, (12, 6): 28}`
which matches the other answers

This example is a bit more complicated than I normally see, and hence the need for the `axis=0` option, if you just want unique values everywhere, you can just miss that out:

```py
# generate random values
x = np.random.negative_binomial(10, 10/(6+10), 100000)

# get table
values, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)

# plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.vlines(values, 0, counts, lw=2)
```

[image: matplotlib output]

R seems to make this sort of thing much more convenient!  The above Python code is just `plot(table(rnbinom(100000, 10, mu=6)))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do a 1-dimensional count with list comprehension.

```
L = [[12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [0, 6], [12, 0], [0, 6], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 6], [12, 6], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [0, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [12, 0], [12, 6], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 6], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [12, 0], [6, 0], [6, 0]]
countey = [tuple(x) for x in L]
freq = {x:countey.count(x) for x in set(countey)}

In [2]: %timeit {x:countey.count(x) for x in set(countey)}
        100000 loops, best of 3: 15.2 µs per loop   

In [4]: print(freq)
Out[4]: {(0, 6): 19, (6, 0): 20, (12, 0): 33, (12, 6): 28}

In [5]: print(freq[(12,6)])
Out[5]: 28
```