# Equivalent of "table" of R in python

Tags: python, r

In **R** we can find the frequency of each item using `table`.
This is an example in **R**:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2)
y <- c("a","a","b","a","a","b")
table(x,y)
#   y
#x   a b
#  1 3 1
#  2 1 1
```

How can I implement it in python while x and y are as DataFrame?
I am totally new in Python and I searched a lot but I was unable to find my answer. I should mention that I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710875/python-equivalent-of-r-table) but I couldn't implement it in my case?

Comment: Try with `crosstab`

Comment: To deal with tablular data, Python has a very good library - [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). Read this 10 minute introduction and you'll be able to handle the table manipulation tasks easily.

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much. `pd.crosstab(X,Y)` was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @TrigonaMinima Thank you, I will go over it. Actually, I am using basic Panda frequently but crosstab was new to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can do this with `crosstab` from `pandas`

```
import numpy as np;
import pandas as pd;
x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]);
y = np.array(["a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b"]);
pd.crosstab(x, y, rownames = ['x'], colnames = ['y']);
#  y  a  b
#x
#1  3  1
#2  1  1
```

Answer (score 12):

counting occurrences
R:

```
sort(table(df$source), decreasing = TRUE)
```

Python Pandas:

```
df.source.value_counts() 
#or
df["source"].value_counts()
```

Source: [R vs Python - a One-on-One Comparison](https://shiring.github.io/r_vs_python/2017/01/22/R_vs_Py_post)

---

For counting occurrences between two columns

with R

```
table(cdc$gender,cdc$smoke100)
```

with python

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['gender'], columns=df['smoke100'])
```

Source: [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47187144/6810785)