# Count duplicates python

Tags: python

Is it possible to count the duplicates from a list?

Let’s say I have this list:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 6]
```

And i want an output like this:

```py
my_list_duplicates = {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 6: 2}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python equivalent of R table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710875/python-equivalent-of-r-table)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 3):

The absolute easiest way is to use the [`collections.Counter` object](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the standard library:

```
>>> import collections
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 6]
>>> dict(collections.Counter(my_list))
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 6: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use an inbuilt function, you could use a hash map to store the count of the values as your iterate through the list

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 6]
my_list_duplicates = {}

for i in my_list:
    if my_list_duplicates.get(i):
        my_list_duplicates[i] += 1
    else:
        my_list_duplicates[i] = 1
    
print(my_list_duplicates)
```

**Output**

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 6: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use Counter from collections package .

```
from collections import Counter
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 6]
list_1 = Counter(my_list)
print(list_1)
```

2.second option is you can iterate it in a loop for each value to find its duplicate and store them in a dictionary .

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 6]
duplicate_dict = {i: my_list.count(i) for i in my_list
print(duplicate_dict)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do that with `count`:

```
my_list_duplicates = {i: my_list.count(i) for i in my_list}
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient.