# Aggregate Data Based on Rows Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
      Date          | ID |  Task |   Description
2016-01-06 00:00:00 | 1  |  010  |   This is text
2016-01-06 00:10:00 | 1  |  020  |   This is text
2016-01-06 00:20:00 | 1  |  010  |   This is text
2016-01-06 01:00:00 | 1  |  020  |   This is text
2016-01-06 01:10:00 | 1  |  030  |   This is text
2016-02-06 00:00:00 | 2  |  010  |   This is text
2016-02-06 00:10:00 | 2  |  020  |   This is text
2016-02-06 00:20:00 | 2  |  010  |   This is text
2016-02-06 01:00:00 | 2  |  020  |   This is text
2016-02-06 01:01:00 | 2  |  030  |   This is text
```

Task `020`usually occurs after task `010` which means that when Task `020` starts means that task `010` ends, same applies for Task `020`, if it comes before any other Task it means that it has stopped.

I need to group by `Task` calculating the ***average duration***, ***total sum*** and ***count*** of each type of task in each `ID`, so I am looking for something like this:

```
ID  | Task | Average | Sum | Count
1   |  010 |   25    | 50  |  2 
1   |  020 |   10    | 20  |  2
etc |  etc |   etc   | etc |  etc
```

There are more IDs but I only care about `010`  and `020`, so whatever number is returned from them is acceptable.

Can someone help me on how to do this in Python?

Comment: How do you know the duration of the **last** task?

Comment: That is one problem I have, I can't really know that duration. However, since I only need `010` and `020`, I wouldn't need to know it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a simple `.groupby()` that you need. You sample output doesn't show any complicated linking between timestamps and Task or ID

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['ID','Task']).size()
```

will give you the count of each unique ID/Task in your data. To do a sum or average, it's similar, but you need a column with something to sum.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38503561/2327328) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response, just one question though. I need to calculate the difference in time in the `Date` column, would this mean that I need to do this before hand somehow?

Comment: you then need to use `.shift()` to create a lead/lag function (diff of t1 and t2) http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), but in sample not numeric column so `col` was added:

```
print (df)
                  Date  ID Task   Description      col
0  2016-01-06 00:00:00   1  010  This is text        1
1  2016-01-06 00:10:00   1  020  This is text        2
2  2016-01-06 00:20:00   1  010  This is text        6
3  2016-01-06 01:00:00   1  020  This is text        1
4  2016-01-06 01:10:00   1  030  This is text        3
5  2016-02-06 00:00:00   2  010  This is text        1
6  2016-02-06 00:10:00   2  020  This is text        8
7  2016-02-06 00:20:00   2  010  This is text        9
8  2016-02-06 01:00:00   2  020  This is text        1

df = df.groupby(['ID','Task'])['col'].agg(['sum','size', 'mean']).reset_index()
print (df)
   ID Task  sum  size  mean
0   1  010    7     2   3.5
1   1  020    3     2   1.5
2   1  030    3     1   3.0
3   2  010   10     2   5.0
4   2  020    9     2   4.5
```

If need aggreagte datetime, id is a bit complicated, because need [timedeltas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
df.Date = pd.to_timedelta(df.Date).dt.total_seconds()
df = df.groupby(['ID','Task'])['Date']
       .agg(['sum','size', 'mean']).astype(np.int64).reset_index()
df['sum'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['sum'])
df['mean'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['mean'])
print (df)
   ID Task             sum  size            mean
0   1  010 00:00:02.904078     2 00:00:01.452039
1   1  020 00:00:02.904081     2 00:00:01.452040
2   1  030 00:00:01.452042     1 00:00:01.452042
3   2  010 00:00:02.909434     2 00:00:01.454717
4   2  020 00:00:02.909437     2 00:00:01.454718
```

For finding difference in column `date`:

```
print (df.Date.dtypes)
object

#if dtype of column is not datetime, first convert
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date )
print (df.Date.diff())
0                NaT
1    0 days 00:10:00
2    0 days 00:10:00
3    0 days 00:40:00
4    0 days 00:10:00
5   30 days 22:50:00
6    0 days 00:10:00
7    0 days 00:10:00
8    0 days 00:40:00
9    0 days 00:01:00
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: So would this mean that I need to calculate somehow the difference in the time in the `Date` column and then do the `groupby`?

Comment: Maybe yes, the best is create sample data with desired output.

Comment: You can get difference by `diff` function, please check my answer. If need something else, please let me know.