# Counting values on two columns Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

Simple question but I have data that looks like:

```
Date           Facility              value
jan-1          Ogden                 1
jan-1          North Haverbrook      2
jan-1          Sinn                  3
jan-1          Lister                2
jan-2          Ogden                 1
jan-2          Corodo                5
jan-2          North Haverbrook      4
jan-3          Ogden                 1
jan-3          Lister                2
```

I need a way to count the values where I get an output that looks like:

```
Facility              value      count
Ogden                 1          3
North Haverbrook      2          1
Sinn                  3          1
Lister                2          2
Corodo                5          1
North Haverbrook      4          1
```

I've been able to count on values alone with `df['value'].value_counts()` but I'd like to somehow `groupby` the Facility as well.

Is there any easy way to go about this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679089/pandas-dataframe-groupby-two-columns-and-get-counts

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['Facility','value']).size().reset_index(name='count')`