# Pandas table computation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a table as follows:

```
+-------+-------+-------------+
| Code  | Event | No. of runs |
+-------+-------+-------------+
|    66 |     1 |             |
|    66 |     1 |           2 |
|    66 |     2 |             |
|    66 |     2 |             |
|    66 |     2 |           3 |
|    66 |     3 |             |
|    66 |     3 |             |
|    66 |     3 |             |
|    66 |     3 |             |
|    66 |     3 |           5 |
|    70 |     1 |             |
|    70 |     1 |             |
|    70 |     1 |             |
|    70 |     1 |           4 |
+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Let's call each row a run. I want to count the no. of runs in each `Event`, separately for each `Code`. Would I need to use the `groupby` function? I have added the expected output in the `No. of runs` column.

Comment: " no. of runs in each Event" means ? can you show the expected df?

Comment: also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679089/pandas-dataframe-groupby-two-columns-and-get-counts

Comment: @anky_91: Added.

Comment: @db18 its same as dupe link

Comment: So just a standard groupby then? `df.groupby(['SPAnr', 'Event']).count()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `groupby` with `transfrom` then `mask` duplicated rows:

```
df['Runs'] = df.groupby(['Code', 'Event'])['Event']\
               .transform('count')\
               .mask(df.duplicated(['Code','Event'], keep='last'), '')
```

Output (add new column to output dataframe from comparison to desired result):

```
    Code     Event    No. of runs Runs
0      66      1                    
1      66      1             2     2
2      66      2                    
3      66      2                    
4      66      2             3     3
5      66      3                    
6      66      3                    
7      66      3                    
8      66      3                    
9      66      3             5     5
10     70      1                    
11     70      1                    
12     70      1                    
13     70      1             4     4
```

Comment: When I run the above command, I get ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: Change the first line to include Event column as aggregation column. `df.groupby(['SPAnr', 'Event'])['Event']`