# create new column counting gender year wise

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
d={'year':['2011','2011','2011','2012','2012','2013','2013'],'sex':['M','F','M','M','F','F','M']}

df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to create new column for performing time series analysis, count of male and female each year. Output should be a dataframe like below:

[image]

I tried d1.groupby(['sex','year']).count(), but it did not do what i expected in output

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Year'], df['sex'])`.

Comment: Use ```size()``` instead of ```count()```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679089/pandas-dataframe-groupby-two-columns-and-get-counts