# Counting Specific Values by Month

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have some data I want to count by month. The column I want count has three different possible values, each representing a different car sold. Here is an example of my dataframe:

```
Date                        Type_Car_Sold
2015-01-01 00:00:00                2
2015-01-01 00:00:00                1
2015-01-01 00:00:00                1
2015-01-01 00:00:00                3
...                               ...
```

I want to make it so I have a dataframe that counts each specific car type sold by month separately, so looking like this:

```
Month       Car_Type_1        Car_Type_2        Car_Type_3         Total_Cars_Sold
1               15                12                17                     44
2                9                18                20                     47
...             ...              ...                ...                    ...
```

How exactly would I go about doing this? I've tried doing:

```
cars_sold = car_data['Type_Car_Sold'].groupby(car_data.Date.dt.month).agg('count')
```

but that just sums up all the cars sold in the month, rather than breaking it down by the total amount of each type sold. Any thoughts?

Comment: My first guess would be a pivot table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the cleanest solution, but this should get you pretty close

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": [datetime(2022,1,1), datetime(2022,1,1), datetime(2022,2,1), datetime(2022,2,1)],
    "Type": [1, 2, 1, 1],
})

df['Date'] = df["Date"].dt.to_period('M')
df['Value'] = 1

print(pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['Date'], columns=['Type'], aggfunc='count'))
```

```
Type       1    2
Date             
2022-01  1.0  1.0
2022-02  2.0  NaN
```

Comment: Aha, that seemed to do the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also pass multiple columns to `groupby`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": [datetime(2022,1,1), datetime(2022,1,1), datetime(2022,2,1), datetime(2022,2,1)],
    "Type": [1, 2, 1, 1],
})

df['Date'] = df["Date"].dt.to_period('M')
```

```py
df.groupby(['Date', 'Type']).size()
```

```
Date     Type
2022-01  1       1
         2       1
2022-02  1       2
dtype: int64
```

This seems to have the unfortunate side effect of excluding keys with zero value. Also the result is multiindexed rows rather than having the index as rows+columns.

For more information on this approach, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17679089/2111778).